# CSV separator for Karate

Tags: csv, parameters, karate, separator, web-api-testing

Can we use a different separator for CSV files in Karate API? I am trying to build a test data file including comma as a parameter value. In Karate if i have a comma then the data after a comma is considered as a separate value. I tried to substitute a pipe symbol instead of comma and it did not work.

Sample File looks as below:

"Param,eterA"| "Param,eterB"

Is there an alternate option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no alternative. But you can enclose values in double-quotes:

```
* text foo =
"""
"par,am1",param2
foo,bar
"""
* csv bar = foo
* match bar == [{ 'par,am1': 'foo', param2: 'bar' }]
```

Comment: Thanks @peter this option works. We will use it for our data set up